# Display n number of telephone numbers in columns

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

**Hello T-SQL community**

I have a project which I need to delivery by end of day Monday. I desperately need your help as I have exhausted all other form of research!

What I am trying to do is as follows

Return a data set which converts table 1 to table 2

**Table 1:**

```
Customer_No Name Telephone_No Address   Street_Name Postcode
=========== ==== ============ ========= =========== ========
635532      Mr X 0771111111   FLAT 1000 BEACH ROAD  BN23 5HT
635532      Mr X 0771112222   FLAT 1000 BEACH ROAD  BN23 5HT
635532      Mr X 01903773333  FLAT 1000 BEACH ROAD  BN23 5HT
635532      Mr X 01903774444  FLAT 1000 BEACH ROAD  BN23 5HT
```

To this...

**Table 2:**

```
Customer_No Name Telephone_No_1 Telephone_No_2 Telephone_No_3 Telephone_No_4 Address   Street_Name Postcode
=========== ==== ============== ============== ============== ============== ========= =========== ======== 
635532      Mr X 0771111111     0771112222     01903773333    01903774444    FLAT 1000 BEACH ROAD  BN23 5HT
```

There could be up to 10 telephone numbers per customer.

The above is shown in the attached picture for clarity

Here is the query that I currently built but it is limited by the number of telephone fields I have hard coded. I will like the columns to be built dynamically

```
Select DISTINCT
       Customer_No,
       Name,
       ( SELECT MIN(REPLACE(Telephone_No, ' ', '') )
         FROM #PSR_Telephone t2
         WHERE t2.customer_No = t1.Customer_No
           AND LEFT(Telephone_No,2) = '07'
       ) AS [Telephone_No_1] , 
       ( SELECT MAX(REPLACE(Telephone_No, ' ', ''))
         FROM #PSR_Telephone t2
         WHERE t2.customer_No = t1.Customer_No
           AND LEFT(Telephone_No,2) = '07'
      ) AS [Telephone_No_2],
      ( SELECT MIN(REPLACE(Telephone_No, ' ', ''))
        FROM #PSR_Telephone t2
        WHERE t2.customer_No = t1.Customer_No
          AND LEFT(Telephone_No,2) <> '07'
      ) AS [Telephone_No_3],
      ( SELECT MAX(REPLACE(Telephone_No, ' ', ''))
        FROM #PSR_Telephone t2
        WHERE t2.customer_No= t1.Customer_No
          AND LEFT(Telephone_No,2) <> '07'
      ) AS [Telephone_No_4],
      Primary_Addressable_Object,
      Street_Name,
      Postcode
from #PSR_Telephone t1
where Customer_No = '635532'
```

I will really appreciate your help on this.

Many thanks!

[image: Example as picture]

Comment: Will it be always four telephone number's per `Customer_No`

Comment: No brother. It can be n number of telephones. I have over half a million customers. Each can have multiple telephone numbers

Comment: You need to perform `Dynamic Pivot`.

Comment: I looked at something like that but all examples show the values as column names rather than how I want them to be. Do you have an example similar to how I want the result set to be?

Comment: You're looking for a pivot table. Search here for `[sql-server] rows to columns`

Comment: What version of SQL server are you using?

Comment: @KenWhite how can he use a pivot table for this?!?

Comment: @StanShaw: Any number of ways. Search the term I provided; you'll see examples of similar tasks in the first few hits.

Comment: @KenWhite I've used pivot tables a bit so I'm familiar with them.  But he doesn't know any of the phone numbers - and they will all be different, so I'm not sure how you would do this.  Can you post a working answer?

Comment: @StanShaw: There is a limit (according to the post) of 10 numbers, which means that the pivot would have to accomodate 10 columns.

Comment: @KenWhite yes, I know that.  But I don't know how to do what you're saying.  Can you please post a working answer?

Comment: @KenWhite excellent my friend. Thanks for the advice. I solved it. Thanks everyone else for trying to help. You all are awesome!

Comment: @AbdulKahar can you post your solution so we can all see the pivot table?  None of the answers have one, so I'm interested to see it.

Comment: I will post the answer on Monday for others benefit

Comment: I just left work now. But promise I will on Monday

Comment: @StanShaw: If I had the time to post a complete answer, I would have done so for the poster of the question. Why would you think I'd suddenly have time to do so for you? :-)

Comment: @KenWhite My apologies.  Fortunately for your ego, posting sarcastic comments is considerably less time-consuming than contributing something meaningful. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you are using SQL-Server 2012 and up

Creating Sample Data:

```
CREATE TABLE #temp (Customer_No INT, Name  VARCHAR(100),  Telephone_No VARCHAR(100),   Address VARCHAR(100), Street_Name VARCHAR(100), Postcode VARCHAR(100))

INSERT INTO #temp
VALUES
(635532,'Mr X','0771111111','FLAT 1000','BEACH ROAD','BN23 5HT'),          
(635532,'Mr X','0771112222','FLAT 1000','BEACH ROAD','BN23 5HT'),       
(635532,'Mr X','01903773333','FLAT 1000','BEACH ROAD','BN23 5HT'),     
(635532,'Mr X','01903774444' ,'FLAT 1000','BEACH ROAD','BN23 5HT')
```

The query using a CTE with CASE statements and windowing function to place the phone numbers under the correct heading:

```
;WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT  #temp.Customer_No, 
          #temp.Name,  
          CASE WHEN Row_number()OVER(partition BY Customer_No ORDER BY Telephone_No) = 1 THEN  #temp.Telephone_No END  AS Telephone_No_1, 
          CASE WHEN Row_number()OVER(partition BY Customer_No ORDER BY Telephone_No) = 2 THEN  #temp.Telephone_No END  AS Telephone_No_2, 
          CASE WHEN Row_number()OVER(partition BY Customer_No ORDER BY Telephone_No) = 3 THEN  #temp.Telephone_No END  AS Telephone_No_3, 
          CASE WHEN Row_number()OVER(partition BY Customer_No ORDER BY Telephone_No) = 4 THEN  #temp.Telephone_No END  AS Telephone_No_4, 
          #temp.Address, 
          #temp.Street_Name, 
          #temp.Postcode 
    FROM #temp)

 SELECT  CTE.Customer_No, 
       CTE.Name, 
       MAX(CTE.Telephone_No_1) Telephone_No_1, 
       MAX(CTE.Telephone_No_2) Telephone_No_2, 
       MAX(CTE.Telephone_No_3) Telephone_No_3, 
       MAX(CTE.Telephone_No_4) Telephone_No_4, 
       CTE.Address, 
       CTE.Street_Name, 
       CTE.Postcode
FROM CTE
GROUP BY      CTE.Customer_No, 
          CTE.Name, 
          CTE.Address,
          CTE.Street_Name,
          CTE.Postcode;
```

Results:

[image]

Below is a dynamic version of the above so you do not need to worry about the number of telephone numbers:

Creating the sample data

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TEMP') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #TEMP; 
CREATE TABLE #temp (Customer_No INT, Name  VARCHAR(100),  Telephone_No VARCHAR(100),   Address VARCHAR(100), Street_Name VARCHAR(100), Postcode VARCHAR(100))

INSERT INTO #temp
VALUES
(635532,'Mr X','0771111111','FLAT 1000','BEACH ROAD','BN23 5HT'),          
(635532,'Mr X','0771112222','FLAT 1000','BEACH ROAD','BN23 5HT'),       
(635532,'Mr X','01903773333','FLAT 1000','BEACH ROAD','BN23 5HT'),     
(635532,'Mr X','01903774444' ,'FLAT 1000','BEACH ROAD','BN23 5HT')
```

The dynamic part of the solution which will generate a query similar to the above query:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TEMP2') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #TEMP2; 

    SELECT  #temp.Customer_No, 
          #temp.Name,  
          Row_number()OVER(partition BY Customer_No ORDER BY Telephone_No) AS rn, 
          #temp.Telephone_No, 
          #temp.Address, 
          #temp.Street_Name, 
          #temp.Postcode INTO #temp2
    FROM #temp


DECLARE @SQL1 VARCHAR(max) ='';

SELECT @SQL1 = '
;WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT  #TEMP2.Customer_No, 
          #TEMP2.Name, ' 

SELECT  @SQL1+='CASE WHEN rn ='+CAST(rn AS VARCHAR)+'THEN  #TEMP2.Telephone_No END  AS Telephone_No_'+CAST(rn AS VARCHAR)+',' FROM #temp2

SELECT @SQL1+= '#TEMP2.Address, 
          #TEMP2.Street_Name, 
          #TEMP2.Postcode 
    FROM #TEMP2)

 SELECT  CTE.Customer_No, 
       CTE.Name,'

SELECT @SQL1+='MAX(CTE.Telephone_No_'+CAST(rn AS VARCHAR)+') AS Telephone_No_'+CAST(rn AS VARCHAR)+','FROM #temp2

SELECT @SQL1+='CTE.Address, 
       CTE.Street_Name, 
       CTE.Postcode
FROM CTE
GROUP BY      CTE.Customer_No, 
          CTE.Name, 
          CTE.Address,
          CTE.Street_Name,
          CTE.Postcode;'



 PRINT(@SQL1)

 EXECUTE (@SQL1)
```

result of the print statement:

[image]

result of the whole query:

[image]

Comment: Best answer so far.  Very nice!

Comment: Only thing is the question states there can be up to 10 phone numbers, so you'll want to edit your answer to include all 10.

Comment: @StanShaw working on a dynamic version so the number of phone number fields will not be an issue

Comment: VR already posted a dynamic version.  However, that will not work because he needs a table that has 10 phone numbers.

Comment: @StanShaw just posted the dynamic version

Comment: @StanShaw just to clarify this customer had 8 numbers built up over time. The problem is we don't know which ones are valid. The point of the exercise is to send the export to an external company to remove the invalid numbers for us. For some reason they wanted the extract to be according to their template. Some customers on the other hand just had one telephone number. Thanks everyone for helping. Kamrans answer is similar to the one I ended up with.

Comment: @AbdulKahar That's a reasonable request.  They don't want to have to write the queries to normalize your data.  However, that does mean that dynamic column numbers would work for you, so it would have been helpful to include that in your original question.  Thank you for the follow-up, though!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is a straight forward pivot. Here is a working example

```
CREATE TABLE #test
  (
     Customer_No  INT,
     NAME         VARCHAR(50),
     Telephone_No NUMERIC(15),
     Address      VARCHAR(50),
     Street_Name  VARCHAR(50),
     Postcode     VARCHAR(50)
  ) 

insert #test values
(635532 ,'Mr X' ,   0771111111  ,'FLAT 1000' ,  'BEACH ROAD' , 'BN23 5HT'),
(635532 ,'Mr X' ,   0771112222  ,'FLAT 1000' ,  'BEACH ROAD' , 'BN23 5HT'),
(635532 ,'Mr X' ,   01903773333 ,'FLAT 1000' ,  'BEACH ROAD' , 'BN23 5HT'),
(635532 ,'Mr X' ,   01903774444 ,'FLAT 1000' ,  'BEACH ROAD' , 'BN23 5HT'),
(635533 ,'Mr X' ,   01903774444 ,'FLAT 1000' ,  'BEACH ROAD' , 'BN23 5HT')

DECLARE @sql  NVARCHAR(max),
        @cnt  INT,
        @incr INT = 1

SELECT @cnt = (SELECT TOP 1 Count(1) AS cnt
               FROM   #test
               GROUP  BY Customer_No
               ORDER  BY cnt DESC) --To get the max phone number count 

SET @sql = '
;with cte as
(
SELECT Row_number()OVER(partition BY Customer_No ORDER BY Telephone_No) as t_list, 
       *
FROM   #test 
)
select Customer_No,Name,'

WHILE @incr <= @cnt -- used just to frame the query 
  BEGIN
      SET @sql += 'max(case when t_list = '+ Cast(@incr AS VARCHAR(15))+ ' then Telephone_No end) as Telephone_No'
                  + Cast(@incr AS VARCHAR(15)) + ','
      SET @incr+=1
  END

SET @sql+= 'Address ,Street_Name ,Postcode from cte group by Customer_No,Name,Address ,Street_Name ,Postcode'

--PRINT @sql

EXEC Sp_executesql @sql
```

**Result:**

```
╔═════════════╦══════╦════════════════╦════════════════╦════════════════╦════════════════╦═══════════╦═════════════╦══════════╗
║ Customer_No ║ Name ║ Telephone_No_1 ║ Telephone_No_2 ║ Telephone_No_3 ║ Telephone_No_4 ║  Address  ║ Street_Name ║ Postcode ║
╠═════════════╬══════╬════════════════╬════════════════╬════════════════╬════════════════╬═══════════╬═════════════╬══════════╣
║      635532 ║ Mr X ║      771111111 ║ 771112222      ║ 1903773333     ║ 1903774444     ║ FLAT 1000 ║ BEACH ROAD  ║ BN23 5HT ║
║      635533 ║ Mr X ║     1903774444 ║ NULL           ║ NULL           ║ NULL           ║ FLAT 1000 ║ BEACH ROAD  ║ BN23 5HT ║
╚═════════════╩══════╩════════════════╩════════════════╩════════════════╩════════════════╩═══════════╩═════════════╩══════════╝
```

Comment: Nice example - only thing is he did say there will be 10 telephone number fields, so you'll want to hard-code your counter to 10 instead of dynamically getting it.

Comment: But the expected result doesnot show all the 10 telephone numbers

Comment: Regardless, if it's possible to have up to 10 numbers, then we can safely assume that his new table (where this data is most likely going) will have 10 telephone number columns.  Who has 10 telephone numbers, I have no idea - why he isn't creating a join table to store them, I also have no idea (especially after going through this mess once).

Answer (score 0):

First, I applaud you for correcting this miserable database structure.  Well done and you will be forever grateful once it's done.

This is tested and it works.  There are probably easier ways to do it (I always avoid dynamic SQL whenever possible), but row_over partitioning is what you're looking for.

```
declare @Table table(
    Customer_No varchar(50), 
    Name varchar(50), 
    Telephone_No varchar(20), 
    Address varchar(50), 
    Street_Name varchar(50), 
    Postcode varchar(50))


insert into @Table
VALUES
(635532, 'Mr. X', '0771111111', 'Flat', '1000 Beach Road', 'Bn23 5HT'),
(635532, 'Mr. X', '0771112222', 'Flat', '1000 Beach Road', 'Bn23 5HT'),
(635532, 'Mr. X', '01903773333', 'Flat', '1000 Beach Road', 'Bn23 5HT')

declare @RowNumberTable table(
    Customer_No varchar(50), 
    Name varchar(50), 
    Telephone_No varchar(50),
    Address varchar(50), 
    Street_Name varchar(50), 
    Postcode varchar(50),
    row_number int)
INSERT INTO @RowNumberTable
SELECT  Customer_No, 
        Name, 
        Telephone_No, 
        Address, 
        Street_Name, 
        Postcode, 
        row_number() over(partition by Customer_No order by Telephone_No) as rn
FROM @Table


SELECT  T1.Customer_No, 
        T1.Name,
        T1.Telephone_No,
        T2.Telephone_No as [Telephone 2],
        T3.Telephone_No as [Telephone 3],
        T4.Telephone_No as [Telephone 4],
        T5.Telephone_No as [Telephone 5],
        T6.Telephone_No as [Telephone 6],
        T7.Telephone_No as [Telephone 7],
        T8.Telephone_No as [Telephone 8],
        T9.Telephone_No as [Telephone 9],
        T10.Telephone_No as [Telephone 10],
        T1.Address,
        T1.Street_Name,
        T1.Postcode
FROM @RowNumberTable T1
LEFT OUTER JOIN @RowNumberTable T2 ON T1.Customer_No = T2.Customer_No AND T2.row_number = 2
LEFT OUTER JOIN @RowNumberTable T3 ON T1.Customer_No = T3.Customer_No AND T3.row_number = 3
LEFT OUTER JOIN @RowNumberTable T4 ON T1.Customer_No = T4.Customer_No AND T4.row_number = 4
LEFT OUTER JOIN @RowNumberTable T5 ON T1.Customer_No = T5.Customer_No AND T5.row_number = 5
LEFT OUTER JOIN @RowNumberTable T6 ON T1.Customer_No = T6.Customer_No AND T6.row_number = 6
LEFT OUTER JOIN @RowNumberTable T7 ON T1.Customer_No = T7.Customer_No AND T7.row_number = 7
LEFT OUTER JOIN @RowNumberTable T8 ON T1.Customer_No = T8.Customer_No AND T8.row_number = 8
LEFT OUTER JOIN @RowNumberTable T9 ON T1.Customer_No = T9.Customer_No AND T9.row_number = 9
LEFT OUTER JOIN @RowNumberTable T10 ON T1.Customer_No = T10.Customer_No AND T10.row_number = 10
WHERE T1.row_number = 1
```

Results:

```
Customer_No                                        Name                                               Telephone_No                                       Telephone 2                                        Telephone 3                                        Telephone 4                                        Telephone 5                                        Telephone 6                                        Telephone 7                                        Telephone 8                                        Telephone 9                                        Telephone 10                                       Address                                            Street_Name                                        Postcode
-------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------- --------------------------------------------------
635532                                             Mr. X                                              01903773333                                        0771111111                                         0771112222                                         NULL                                               NULL                                               NULL                                               NULL                                               NULL                                               NULL                                               NULL                                               Flat                                               1000 Beach Road                                    Bn23 5HT
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a table schema that looks something like this (you need a way to uniquely identify each row):

```
create table dbo.customer
(
  customer_no  int         not null ,
  telephone_no varchar(32) not null ,
  name         varchar(32) not null ,
  address      varchar(32) not null ,
  street_name  varchar(32) not null ,
  postcode     varchar(32) not null ,

  primary key clustered ( customer_no , telephone_no ) ,

)
```

Something like this should do get you the table rotation you want:

```
with t1 as (
  select customer_no  =      c.customer_no    ,
         telephone_no = min( c.telephone_no )
  from dbo.customer c
  group by c.customer_no
) ,
c as (
  select c.*
  from dbo.customer c
  join t1 on t1.customer_no  = c.customer_no
         and t1.telephone_no = c.telephone_no
) ,
t2 as (
  select customer_no  =      c.customer_no    ,
         telephone_no = min( c.telephone_no )
  from dbo.customer c
  join t1           t on t.customer_no  = c.customer_no
                     and t.telephone_no < c.telephone_no
  group by c.customer_no
),
t3 as (
  select customer_no  =      c.customer_no    ,
         telephone_no = min( c.telephone_no )
  from dbo.customer c
  join t2           t on t.customer_no  = c.customer_no
                     and t.telephone_no < c.telephone_no
  group by c.customer_no
),
t4 as (
  select customer_no  =      c.customer_no    ,
         telephone_no = min( c.telephone_no )
  from dbo.customer c
  join t3           t on t.customer_no  = c.customer_no
                     and t.telephone_no < c.telephone_no
  group by c.customer_no
),
t5 as (
  select customer_no  =      c.customer_no    ,
         telephone_no = min( c.telephone_no )
  from dbo.customer c
  join t4           t on t.customer_no  = c.customer_no
                     and t.telephone_no < c.telephone_no
  group by c.customer_no
),
t6 as (
  select customer_no  =      c.customer_no    ,
         telephone_no = min( c.telephone_no )
  from dbo.customer c
  join t5           t on t.customer_no  = c.customer_no
                     and t.telephone_no < c.telephone_no
  group by c.customer_no
),
t7 as (
  select customer_no  =      c.customer_no    ,
         telephone_no = min( c.telephone_no )
  from dbo.customer c
  join t6           t on t.customer_no  = c.customer_no
                     and t.telephone_no < c.telephone_no
  group by c.customer_no
),
t8 as (
  select customer_no  =      c.customer_no    ,
         telephone_no = min( c.telephone_no )
  from dbo.customer c
  join t7           t on t.customer_no  = c.customer_no
                     and t.telephone_no < c.telephone_no
  group by c.customer_no
),
t9 as (
  select customer_no  =      c.customer_no    ,
         telephone_no = min( c.telephone_no )
  from dbo.customer c
  join t8           t on t.customer_no  = c.customer_no
                     and t.telephone_no < c.telephone_no
  group by c.customer_no
),
t10 as (
  select customer_no  =      c.customer_no    ,
         telephone_no = min( c.telephone_no )
  from dbo.customer c
  join t9           t on t.customer_no  = c.customer_no
                     and t.telephone_no < c.telephone_no
  group by c.customer_no
)
select customer_no = c.customer_no ,
       name        = c.name        ,
       addr        = c.address     ,
       street      = c.street_name ,
       postcode    = c.postcode    ,
       tel_1       = t1.telephone_no ,
       tel_2       = t2.telephone_no ,
       tel_3       = t2.telephone_no ,
       tel_4       = t2.telephone_no ,
       tel_5       = t2.telephone_no ,
       tel_6       = t2.telephone_no ,
       tel_7       = t2.telephone_no ,
       tel_8       = t2.telephone_no ,
       tel_9       = t2.telephone_no ,
       tel_10      = t2.telephone_no
from      c
left join t1  on t1.customer_no  = c.customer_no and t1.telephone_no  = c.telephone_no
left join t2  on t2.customer_no  = c.customer_no and t2.telephone_no  = c.telephone_no
left join t3  on t3.customer_no  = c.customer_no and t3.telephone_no  = c.telephone_no
left join t4  on t4.customer_no  = c.customer_no and t4.telephone_no  = c.telephone_no
left join t5  on t5.customer_no  = c.customer_no and t5.telephone_no  = c.telephone_no
left join t6  on t6.customer_no  = c.customer_no and t6.telephone_no  = c.telephone_no
left join t7  on t7.customer_no  = c.customer_no and t7.telephone_no  = c.telephone_no
left join t8  on t8.customer_no  = c.customer_no and t8.telephone_no  = c.telephone_no
left join t9  on t9.customer_no  = c.customer_no and t9.telephone_no  = c.telephone_no
left join t10 on t10.customer_no = c.customer_no and t10.telephone_no = c.telephone_no
;
```